# OpenSea isApprovedForAll and proxy addresses functionality

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, opensea

I found an explanation [here](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/1-structuring-your-smart-contract#opensea-whitelisting-optional), but I want to clarify some moments.

Is the `isApprovedForAll` method needs to be overwritten in `ERC721Tradable` if we need to get rid of excess fees for approval? Is proxy addresses for each user unique? If it isn't, do we need to add something like

```
       if (_operator == address(proxy_address)) {
            return true;
        }
```

in `isApprovedForAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As displayed in [deploy script for OpenSea Creatures contracts](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/d0999de0a735b3b5c41feb7663ab88dc6407158a/contracts/CreatureAccessoryLootBox.sol#L25-L26) (lines 25-26), there is one address for each network:

```
  let proxyRegistryAddress = "";
  if (network === 'rinkeby') {
          proxyRegistryAddress = "0xf57b2c51ded3a29e6891aba85459d600256cf317";
  } else {
          proxyRegistryAddress = "0xa5409ec958c83c3f309868babaca7c86dcb077c1";
  }
```

So in most cases, we don't need to hardcode it inside our contracts.

Comment: So, does it mean that for production I can simply hardcode the value using a constant modifier to save on a bit of gas fee? In opensea creatures contract there is no functionality to edit a proxy address, but what are the guarantees that proxy won't change?